# Windows Service Installation using installshield

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer, installshield

I have a windows service. How do I install and start it using installshield 2010?

Comment: what did you try? Which version of IS are you using? check answers here as well: http://community.installshield.com/showthread.php?t=175189

Comment: take a look  at this link http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=175189

Comment: This is what you're after...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994725/how-do-i-create-an-installshield-le-project-to-install-a-windows-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InstallScript have the following functions `ServiceAddService` and `ServiceStartService` for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

if it is an basic msi project you can create in component level

create a folder with component ,assigne your service.exe to the component.
then go to component view\select assigned component\advancesettings\services .here you can create the service
and also create events which you want to do like install-start