# Open a vdproj file with VS Community 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vdproj

I retrieved a C++ VS project from 2011 and it has a `Install-win32.vdproj` I guess it has to be the file I need to open in order to build the project.

Unfortunately Visual Studio 2017 seems not to recognize this kind of file. Is there any ways to interpret it or convert it?

Comment: Yes indeed, I was just wondering what it's for. But it's possible to open this with the MVS 2017 Installer extension tool.

Comment: Answers to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028746/visual-studio-vdproj-is-incompatible suggest that this project type was deprecated as far back as VS2012.
This one has some steps for migrating to a different framework:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571268/visual-studio-2012-windows-service-vdproj-project-migration

Comment: The feature was removed in VS2012, it was causing more problems than it solved.  But it is still [available as an add-in](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)

Answer (score 2):

For VS2017, use the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects.  Download link is below.  Be sure to close Visual Studio before running the installer:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Comment: Solve my problem on VS2019. I needed open old project.