# InstallShield Visual Studio not installing Service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield

I have a Service project within .NET using C#.
I have then used InstallShield 2012 within Visual Studio to create a MSI that should install my Service, however when I run the MSI, theService never shows in the Services window.

I have created the Service by creating a Component, Advanced Settings -> Created new Service. Then have added the whole /bin/debug of my C# project (since I wasn't sure only .exe would be enough)

However, I am not sure how to tell the InstallShield to go ahead and do the actual install of my service. I don't want users to do it manually via command line by InstallUtil tool.

Is it possible to tell InstallShield to do the install of the Service?

Comment: Have you added a `ServiceProcessInstaller` component to your service project?

Answer (score 5):

You have to go to the properties of the primary output of your service, then the COM & .NET tab, and place a check in the "Installer Class" check box.

For more info, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994725/how-do-i-create-an-installshield-le-project-to-install-a-windows-service/13162618#13162618)

Comment: Thanks. I've been seeing mentions of this property box, but they all reference it during the actual installer setup phase. I couldn't find it after the fact.