# Visual Studio 2012 InstallShield Nightmare

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield

Being forced to use the garbage version of LE in VS 2012, I cannot get things to build because it is telling me that my install folder path is too long.  It literally looks like it is creating the same path, verbatim, inside of another folder.  First this fails on the DVD so can I disable that?  Second, this appears to be controlled by the variable ISProductFolder but I cannot find how to modify that location.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: If you remove the 80% of your question that's nothing but complaining, and just leave the part that's an actual question, this would be much better (and much more useful for future readers doing a search to find a solution to a problem). If you have complaints about Microsoft's decisions, please post them at a Microsoft site. This is not the appropriate place.

Comment: I went into the Project Assistant, on the Application Information tab and clicked the "Edit the default installation location" link. I changed that to a simple folder and everything built without issues.

I then installed everything with no issues on the Windows 2012 server I am using and the install did place everything in the correct folder. That stated, it installed an application and NOT a Windows Service. I was never asked for a username/password and there is no Windows Service entry in the Services tab on the server. 
Is there some other setting I need to use here?

Comment: Found it - if Mongo answers this question with this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994725/how-do-i-create-an-installshield-le-project-to-install-a-windows-service - I would very gladly submit it as the answer.  Thank you for the post!

Comment: @KenTola, as the Kevin White mentioned in his comment, just "stop complaining" - and just describe the error or issue in your questions.

Comment: I both took off everything that was negative AND provided the solution I found elsewhere.  Ken was correct, I was frustrated, but the current issue is about 80% smaller...  One thing that would be useful is to credit an answer found elsewhere but I do not know how to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it is not surprise that each setup tool has its problems. Please note that there are no tools which can accurately detect your application dependencies. The best a tool can do is make suggestions. This is why most setup developers determine the dependencies themselves and manually include them in the installer.

If you're not happy with InstallShield, you can try a different setup tool: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

The free version of Advanced Installer includes a [Visual Studio setup project](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-ext-vs.html) which may help.

Comment: Whoever this is, you answered the EXACT same way to many other posts - perhaps not writing verbatim answers would be more useful...

Comment: @KenTola, did you already tried what is suggested in answer? if not, please try first.

Comment: You just provided a list of software - that does nothing to provide a solution to this issue.

Comment: Sure, i provided a guidance to your issue, and it not a pin-point fix to your exact problem.

Comment: That is like pointing me to a directory of hosting sites and saying that you  solved a problem on coding a website.  The point is you have said this exact same thing in many other places - we get it, nice page but not useful in solving any of the issues asked by me and others.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem as @KenTola.  Would like a fix to the problem and not just a work around, especially when it involves a completely different set up tool.  Like saying, hey, I have a C# problem.  Solution: Try PHP. ???? Really?