# How to get to the "Properties" dialogue for the Primary Output of a Windows Service in InstallShield LE / VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-services, installshield-le

I'm trying to set up an InstallShield LE installer for a Windows Service. I'm using VS 2012 Premium and InstallShield LE. I'm looking at this SO question ...

> [How do i create an InstallShield LE project to install a windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994725/how-do-i-create-an-installshield-le-project-to-install-a-windows-service/13162618#13162618)

The accepted answer has these steps...

> - Run through the InstallShield project assistant and add the primary output of your service to the Application files section.
> - After you are down with the project assistant, double click the "Files" item under step two of the setup project.
> - Right click on the primary output of your service, and go to properties.
> - Click the "COM and .NET Settings" tab, and place a check in the "Installer Class" checkbox.

The answer has a screen shot of a **Properties** dialogue box for the "*primary output of your service*".

I am unable to get to this dialogue box.

- I double click the "Files" item under step two of the setup project. I do not see anything that says "primary output".
- If I left click on the project in the "Source computer's folders" on the left side, I get "Primary output from " on the right, under "Source computer's files".
- If I right click on the entry, "Primary output from ", I don't see a "Properties" entry in the context menu. There is only "Copy" and "Resolve Project Output ...".

**How can I get to the Properties dialogue shown in the screen shot shown in the SO question?**

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me solve the problem ...

> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb88b2/simple-steps-to-create-setup-file-using-install-shield-le-fr/

I had not added the project outputs inside the *Project Assistant* and so they didn't show when I double clicked the "Files" under *Step 2* of the *Setup* project.

Being brand new to InstallShield LE, the above link was **very** useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Files' in the 'Destination computer's files' section you typically have the primary output of a VS solution (but in general whatever you are going to create an installer for). Right click on top of the primary output and click 'Properties'.

This will open the properties table.