# How to install windows service using visual studio 2012 and instalshields limited edition

Tags: windows, service, visual-studio-2012, installshield

How to install windows service using visual studio 2012 and instalshields limited edition?
I tried: [How do i create an InstallShield LE project to install a windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994725/how-do-i-create-an-installshield-le-project-to-install-a-windows-service)

But that works only for all project where I have already had the project isntaller file with the service isntaller and the service process installer added to the design view of the project installer file.

Has anyone managed to make this working?

Thank u

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994725/how-do-i-create-an-installshield-le-project-to-install-a-windows-service

Answer (score 1):

For better or for worse, InstallShield LE was designed to have the same features as Visual Studio Deployment Projects.  This means using InstallUtil custom actions to reinvent the wheel as MSI's ServiceInstall and ServiceControl are not exposed.

Options are either to a)  upgrade to InstallShield Professional, b) switch to Windows Installer XML or c) blend WiX Merge Modules with InstallShield LE.

The concept is to create a merge module project that encapsulates your service EXE  and the consume that in InstallShield LE.

See:
[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Windows Services](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ServiceInstall component with InstallShield LE, see:

[How do i create an InstallShield LE project to install a windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994725/how-do-i-create-an-installshield-le-project-to-install-a-windows-service)