# Visual Studio 2010 setup project for VS 2012 Windows Service

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to use VS 2010 to create a Setup project for a C# VS 2012 Windows Service?
I clicked Add Project Output and in the popup there is no where i can attach the 2012 service project.

Is there any tutorial i can find where it shows how to do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS2012 does not support the project setups that VS2010 has. you can however enable installsheild LE (Lite Edition) for VS2012 and do it this way:

[How do i create an InstallShield LE project to install a windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994725/how-do-i-create-an-installshield-le-project-to-install-a-windows-service/13162618#13162618)

Comment: Thank you ! I have seen some stackoverflow articles that suggested to use VS 2010 for setup. I will try InstallShield .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how involved your project is and what Framework it is targeting. You will not be able to use the Wizard, or add a 2012 Project Output in VS2010 because it will not recognize it. You should be able to create a blank installer and add the executable and all ancillary files to it, and it should work. I would be more likely to invest the time to learn [`WIX`](http://wix.codeplex.com/) or another installer that will be supported.