# How to make InstallShield change Installed Windows Service's Startup Type

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-services, installshield, installshield-le

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and InstallShield LE.

Thanks to the answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994725/how-do-i-create-an-installshield-le-project-to-install-a-windows-service/13162618#answer-13162618), I am able to successfully install a Windows Service to a computer using the InstallShield LE installer.

I'm wondering how I can set the Startup Type for the Window's Service to "Automatic" within InstallShield? Right now it's defaulting to "Manual".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to make InstallShield install a service with a certain Startup Type.

In regard to Window's Services built through Visual Studio, under the `ProjectInstaller.cs` auto-generated class, set the serviceInstaller class's StartType property to be "Automatic".

Answer (score 1):

In InstallShield, in the Installation Designer, under Organization -> Setup Design, expand your service, then go to Advanced Settings.   Under Services select your service.  There is a property named StartType which you can set to Automatic.  This works for InstallShield 2011 and 2015 (those are the two versions we have used at my company).