# Reboot warning message while uninstalling

Tags: windows, service, installshield, uninstallation

I have my windows based application using visual studio 2013 and InstallShield 2013 limited edition windows installer.

When I am uninstalling my existing application it will shows "The setup must update files or services that cannot be updated while the system is running. if you choose to continue, a reboot will be required to complete the setup" like this...

How can I Suppress this window when I am uninstalling my application without stopping the services manually? Suggest me any approach be using code or InstallShield configuration.

Comment: InstallShield LE uses installer classes to install and uninstall services, so you'd override the uninstall method in the installer class, stopping your service with code and then calling base.Uninstall().

Comment: Can you tell me the steps in installshield? I didn't saw installer class anywhere in installshield, I'm new to installshield. @PhilDW

Comment: As far as I know, if you really are installing a service you are using installer classes because that's what LE does, as here with a project installer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994725/how-do-i-create-an-installshield-le-project-to-install-a-windows-service